# Call URL with GET parameters C#

Tags: c#, http, get, webclient

I have 2 sites, one of them is a web service and the other one is a "normal" site.

In the "normal" site I have a page in which it send a mail by getting some parameter, so if in my browser I manually type this URL:

```
http://localhost/Web/page/page.aspx?id=23&emailus=mail@mail.com
```

It creates a specific mail for that user for that id.

The problem is that I want to call that URL in my web service, so when all data get created, after that it will send the mail from that URL, but I cant make it work, I've tried this:

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/Web/page/page.aspx?id=" + idtable + "&emailus=" + email));
```

And:

```
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

                webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/Web/page/page.aspx?id=" + idtable + "&emailus=" + email);

            });
```

Both of them give my a timeout exception and the mail never sends.

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: You need to encode each url parameters. Use the static method UrlEncode of `System.Net.WebUtility` (or `System.Web.HttpUtility `)

Comment: don't use task.run in an asp.net context, or anything that forces asp.net to manage threads against the way it is designed.